# mySQL subquery to see if

Tags: mysql

- Each Album has many Icons.
- An Icon is current if its field `current <> 0`
- An album is current if each of its icons are current.

I need to know:
**For each album, is the album current?**

I tried:

```
 "SELECT *, ".$subquery." AS current FROM tbl_album"
```

where `$subquery` is:

```
 SELECT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tbl_icon2album JOIN tbl_album ON tbl_album.id=tbl_icon2album.albumID WHERE tbl_icon2album.b_current_in_timeproof = 0)
```

But this does not work. I get the message "*1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax*"

Interestingly, the subquery works fine as a stand-alone. Also, the main query works fine as follows:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS current FROM tbl_album
```

So if the sub-query works, and the main query works, why won't they work together?

**post scriptum:**
A working solution for this problem was presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951233/mysql-get-status-of-all-records-from-associative-table).

Comment: What if an album has 0 icons? Is it then current?

Comment: because `SELECT *, SELECT EXISTS (...) FROM...` is far from correct syntax, if you had been writing it all in one piece I imagine you'd have been more likely to see that.

Comment: Indeed, the syntax error was that I needed parentheses around the subquery. However, the correct result was given by Michael Anderson's solution

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a subquery here, try this:

```
SELECT  a.albumId,
        IF( SUM(IF(i.current<>1,1,0)) = 0,'Current','Not Current') as IsCurrent
FROM    tbl_album a
LEFT JOIN tbl_icon2album i ON i.albumId = a.albumId
GROUP BY a.albumId
```

Updated query to reflect if an album is current based on the sum of icon current statuses.

Updated: changed i.current<>0 to i.current<>1

Comment: Not sure if that works. I need to verify EACH icon of the album, not ONE icon. However, I believe my error is that I need extra parentheses around the sub-query...

Comment: Yeah as soon as I posted it, I saw the issue. I just updated. Basically sum up all the icon states - if they are current it counts as 0, if not it counts as 1. if the total sum is > 0 then the album has an icon that is not current and thus the album is not current.

Comment: Thank you, sir. This works! Now, I understand that this query could run faster with `EXISTS`. Is that correct?

Comment: Turns out to be not correct after all, because Michael's query evaluates all icons of all albums in one fell swoop. It should evaluate all icons of each album; separately per album

Comment: Thanks for the update. The query doesn't evaluate all of them. It's the group by that limits each album to evaluate only it's own icons. I think the confusion is that the line i.current<>0 should be i.current<>1. try that, as right now it's saying if there is an active icon, then it is not current. Swapping that to 1 will fix. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I opened another question for this matter; and got a working result there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951233/mysql-get-status-of-all-records-from-associative-table

Answer (score 0):

So I am taking a few guesses here as you didn't supply the structure of the tables. You are trying to select all albums, and state if they are "current" or not, where "current" is specified as them having one or more icons that are current:

```
SELECT 
    IF(
        tbl_icon2album.current != 0,
        "current",
        "not current"
    ) AS isAlbumCurrent,
    tbl_album.*
FROM tbl_album
LEFT JOIN tbl_icon2album ON 
    tbl_album.id=tbl_icon2album.albumID
GROUP BY tbl_album.id;
```

Comment: If there are five icons attached to one album, you're not evaluating the current status of each icon with this query. You'll only be evaluating one, as you're not using an aggregate function to roll up the statuses.

Comment: What Michael Anderson says. I tested this and it does not produce the right result.

Comment: You are correct. I was reading the question as "if one icon is current" rather than "if **all** icons are current". Your solution is correct. Upvoted. Actually I'm not even checking if one is, just the first one... All flavours of wrong here, move along.