# MySql get status of all records from associative table

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following DataBase:

```
CREATE TABLE album ( id int );

INSERT INTO album (id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);

CREATE TABLE icon_album ( albumID int, current int );

INSERT INTO icon_album (albumID, current) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 1),

(2, 1),
(2, 0),

(3, 0),
(3, 0);
```

I would like to get the following result

```
albums:  id   status
         1      1
         2      0
         3      0
         4      0
```

**What is the MySql query that would give me the correct result?**

P.S. 1: This is my second question for this problem. This [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938822/mysql-subquery-to-see-if/19938910#19938910) did not yield a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT a.id, IF(i.current IS NULL, 0, current) AS status
FROM album a LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT albumID, MIN(current) AS current
    FROM icon_album
    GROUP BY albumID
) i ON a.id = i.albumID
```

Comment: Beautiful! This query produces the right result. Thank you so much!

Comment: I would *never* have been able to find this solution myself. Thanks again!

Comment: Why use `IF(something IS NULL, 0, something)` when there's an `IFNULL(something, 0)`? Or, still better, `COALESCE(something, 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
"SELECT albumID AS id, if(SUM(current)>1,1,0) AS status FROM icon_album GROUP BY albumID"
```